# Django templates and unipath

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use unipath module in my django project as it mentioned in Two Scoops of Django book and something works not as intended.
In my settings.py I have this:

```
    from unipath import Path

    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [(BASE_DIR.child('templates'),)],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.child('static')
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.child('media')
```

And with that settings I'm getting TemplateDoesNotExist exception:

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:

    /var/www/(Path('/home/user/my_project/project/templates'),)/myapp/index.html (File does not exist)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved this problem!
Need to edit TEMPLATES' 'DIRS' string in settings.py to:

```
'DIRS': (BASE_DIR.child('templates'),),
```